# Action UI Just on Android Notification Bar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-pendingintent, android-notification-bar

When using the stopwatch function in the Android Clock application, the timer can be stopped, lapped and reset all from the notification bar. Except for reset, clicking on any of these action buttons does not require the application UI to be shown. How would I implement similar functionality in my application where the user can click on an action button in the notification bar and have some code run on the backend without having to show an Activity?

[image: Stopwatch in Notification Bar]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: I read that guide. It seems like I need to set up an action using a [`PendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), so my question is what kind of `PendingIntent` to use.

Comment: You use whatever pending intent you need to, it does not sound like you coded anything so we cannot really help you without specifics